# Binding mouse events on 'stop' motion in tkinter python3

Tags: python, events, binding, tkinter, mouse

Is it possible to trigger a function when the mouse stop moving?
For example, I have a scale, and I want to trigger a function when I still holding a button and stop dragging. I used 'ButtonRelease-1' but I had to release a mouse button to be able to trigger a function, it's not what I want.
Hope you guys can help me.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't see any methods in **tkinter** which can do that. But you can use **pygame**. I think it has the right thing for you. [PYGAME MOUSE METHOD](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html#pygame.mouse.get_rel)

Comment: The definition of "stop moving" is subject to interpretation, but you could hack something together by binding a callback to clicking on the `Scale` that starts a timer, and a callback to mouse movement that resets the counter. If it reaches zero, stop counting and fire the desired function. However, I would strongly recommend not doing this, as stopping movement on a `Scale` will be just as vague to users as it is to other programmers, including those involved with creating Tcl or Tkinter.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't bind to "mouse stopped moving". However, you can bind to `<B1-Motion>`, and with each callback set a timer to run in the future. If the mouse hasn't moved within that time the function will be called. Within that function you could use `event_generate` to generate a custom `<<MouseStopped>>` event. If the mouse moves before the timer expires, reset the timer.

You get the exactly the same effect as if you bound to the mouse not moving.

Comment: Thanks so much for the tip. I gave it a try by using after() method, and it works. But there is one small bug still bugs me. If I keep dragging a slider,  the function still fires within the time given in the after() method. Is there the way to check the mouse movement whether it's moving or not?

Comment: @ryanvolap: there is no way to check if the mouse is moving. Though, you can save the coordinates of the cursor with every `<Motion>` event, and then compare it to the current location.